# mod_deflate is working but send wrong headers

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, gzip, mod-deflate

I'm using mod_deflate to server gzip content for js and css files.

Using curl I can see that it works and I can see the code but Chrome still thinks it's gzip content and NOT stylesheets/javascript so it won't render them.

Chrome says:
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-gzip.

So I guess that's apache sending wrong headers. But I don't know how to fix it.

Anyone has an idea?

Server is running Ubuntu 12 64 bits, with apache2.

Thanks!

Comment: What were the response headers?

Comment: @MichaelHampton it was: Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 21139
Content-Type: application/x-gzip

Comment: Your Content-Type is definitely wrong. How did you set this up?

Comment: I now switched to nginx, and same error that's weird. Not the same setup at all with gzip options turned on... I'm still searching

Comment: You can check it out here thanks! http://54.245.109.20/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your links are wrong.

You've made links to `file.css.gz`, which just serves the gzipped file directly.

Instead, you should link to `file.css`. The web browser will figure out that the gzipped file is there (nginx) and serve it, or will compress it itself.

Comment: But why it used to work on http://vinpin.com for example? Thanks

Comment: @Tom: It didn't work on `vinpin.com`. You had it configured to serve the gzipped files directly on `vinpin.com` and in instead served the regular files. That's an example of something *not* working. Computers are working when they do what you tell them to do.

Comment: But how come it was working before? Now I configured nginx to automatically compress css and js. It seems to work for real now, basically once this is activated all I have to do is serve the files the way I served them before right? Thanks

Comment: @Tom: It wasn't working before. It just happened that it was doing what you actually wanted it to do while it was broken and not doing what it was told to do.